# Grant permissions with Windows authenticator for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I created a Local Server for SQL Server 2022 on my laptop. When I log in with my Windows authenticator, I can't create a new database or delete, and I can't give permissions to my user. Any idea how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set the `sa` password during installation?

Comment: @hardCode no, I tried to change it (guessing which was it) and SSMS allowed me, but when I tried to log in with SA, SSMS didnt let me sign in

Comment: Try running SSMS with the same account that installed the server. When creating the initial users often the one doing the install gets sysadmin role by default.

Comment: Is your Windows login a member of the PC's Administrator's group? If not, then you'll need to be added, otherwise you have no way to log into your SQL Server instance as an administrator, and you'll have to uninstall and reinstall SQL Server.

Comment: Reinstallation isn't needed, @HardCode . There is [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver16) on what to do.